# NIVEIS DE ACESSO - PHP + SQL SERVER

Tags: php, sql-server

Tenho uma Tabela no meu DB com as seguintes colunas : Usuário , Senha , Nivel e preciso fazer com que cada nível relacionado a pessoa ela seja redirecionada para paginas diferentes . Como posso realizar isso ?

Segue minha linha de código :

```
conexão.login.php

  <?php 
session_start();
            $serverName = "";
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"" );
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
                 if ($conn === false) {
                  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

 $user = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $query = ("SELECT * FROM COLUNA WHERE LOGIN LIKE '$user' AND SENHA LIKE '$password'");
 $params = array(); 
 $options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);
  $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
       if ($row_count > 0) {

   $dados = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
   $_SESSION['email'] = $user;
   $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
   $_SESSION['nivel'] = $dados["NIVEL"];

                if( $_SESSION['nivel'] = 11){
                  header('location:x.php');
       }
       else{
       header('location:y.php');
       }}
        else {
    //Destrói
    session_destroy();

    //Limpa
    unset ($_SESSION['email']);
    unset ($_SESSION['password']);
        unset ($_SESSION['nivel']);


    //Redireciona para a página de autenticação
    header('location:index.php');

}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forma mais fácil nesse caso é usar sua sessão para redirecionar quando o usuário fizer login igual vc fez no treco do código $_SESSION['nivel'] == 11

faz em uma pagina separada estas configurações e use um require_once

e na pagina destas configurações faça algo parecido como

```
session_start();
$nivel = $_SESSION['nivel'];
//Inicio de redirecionamento por niveis de acesso
if ($nivel == 1)
 { header("Location: pagina_do_nivel_1.php") }
elseif ($nivel == 2)
 { header("Location: pagina_do_nivel_2.php") }
```

....

```
else { header("Location: nivel_nao_especificado.php") }
```

E dentro de cada pagina colocar um verificador tbm para evitar que o usuário acesso manualmente

Comment: Muito Obrigado :) Funcionou perfeitamente.